# No module named exceptions - scrapy pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to write a mysql pipeline for scrapy, but I get an "Import error":

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.3-py2.7-win32.egg\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 39,    
in load_object raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)
ImportError: Error loading object 'tutorial.pipelines.MySQLStore': No module named exceptions
```

The code for the pipeline is:

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.core.exceptions import DropItem
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

import time
import MySQLdb.cursors

class FilterWords(object):
    """A pipeline for filtering out items which contain certain words in their
    description"""

    # put all words in lowercase
   words_to_filter = ['politics', 'religion']

       def process_item(self, spider, item):
       print spider
       for word in self.words_to_filter:
           if word in unicode(item['description']).lower():
               raise DropItem("Contains forbidden word: %s" % word)
       else:
           return item

class MySQLStore(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # @@@ hardcoded db settings
        # TODO: make settings configurable through settings
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('',
            db='',
            user='',
            passwd='',
            cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True
        )

    def process_item(self, spider, item):
        # run db query in thread pool
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
        query.addErrback(self.handle_error)

        return item

    def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
        # create record if doesn't exist. 
        # all this block run on it's own thread
        tx.execute("select * from scrapytest where link = %s", (item['link'][0], ))
        result = tx.fetchone()
        if result:
            log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            tx.execute(\
                "insert into scrapytest (title, link, desc) "
                "values (%s, %s, %s)",
                (item['title'][0],
                item['link'][0],
                item['desc'][0])
            )
           log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

I have tried to use other pipelines (like Json) and they work, but here there is some kind of import problem that I don't understand.

Comment: I don't think you pasted the pipeline code in correctly. Look at the indentation, and class MySQLStore is empty.

Comment: Yes, I was a bit careless when I pasted the code, I've corrected that now, however, I do not think this is the problem in my original script where the indentation is correct. Any other suggestions? @JosefAssad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is *very* clear!

```
ImportError: ... No module named exceptions
```

You are trying to import `exceptions`, but there is no such module. Look at the code where you import that module:

```
from scrapy.core.exceptions import DropItem
```

This should be:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
```

There is no `scrapy.core.exceptions` module.

Comment: Great, thank you for helping me out with this. I did as you suggested and the problem seem to have disappeared. But now I get: 
"ImportError: Import by filename is not supported."
Is this a related problem or a completely different one? Again, thanks for helping!